# Replacing values in data frame with other values in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have two data frame `tab_A` and `tab_b` with simular column names: `group`, `V1:V3`. First one has additional col `id`. Every rows in `tab_A` has values within `V1:V3`.

```
tab_A <- data.frame(cbind(id = rep(c("01", "02", "03"),3),
                       gr = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                       V1 = c(NA,NA,"A","B",NA,NA,NA,"C","C"),
                       V2 = c("A",NA,NA,NA,"B","B","C",NA,NA),
                       V3 = c(NA,"A",NA,"B",NA,"B",NA,"C",NA)))
tab_b <- data.frame(cbind(gr = c("A","B","C"), V1 = c(5,2,9), V2 = c(0,1,5), 
                       V3 = c(4,4,3)))
```

I would like to replace not `<NA>` values by values from `tab_b` with controlling columns `V1:V3`.
Desired output is below:

```
output
id gr   V1   V2   V3
01  A <NA>    0 <NA>
02  A <NA> <NA>    4
03  A    5 <NA> <NA>
01  B    2 <NA>    4
02  B <NA>    1 <NA>
03  B <NA>    1    4
01  C <NA>    5 <NA>
02  C    9 <NA>    3
03  C    9 <NA> <NA>
```

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Since the dimensions of `tab_A` and `tab_b` don’t match I’m not sure how you want to replace values in the former by values in the latter. Can you clarify this?

Comment: sorry, but I don't find problem with dimension. In `tab_A$gr` I have three unique value: A, B, C. I want to replace values within further columns by values from `tab_b`. i.e. `subset(tab_b, gr=="A", select = "V1")` = 5  should be on place A `subset(tab_A[3,], gr=="A", select = "V1")` and so forth for each values except `<NA>`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using subsetting to create a new dataframe:

```
tab_A <- data.frame(cbind(id = rep(c("01", "02", "03"),3),
                       gr = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                       V1 = c(NA,NA,"A","B",NA,NA,NA,"C","C"),
                       V2 = c("A",NA,NA,NA,"B","B","C",NA,NA),
                       V3 = c(NA,"A",NA,"B",NA,"B",NA,"C",NA)))
tab_b <- data.frame(cbind(gr = c("A","B","C"), V1 = c(5,2,9), V2 = c(0,1,5), 
                       V3 = c(4,4,3)))

df <- data.frame(id = tab_A$id,
                 gr = tab_A$gr, 
                 V1 = tab_b$V1[tab_A$V1], 
                 V2 = tab_b$V2[tab_A$V2], 
                 V3 = tab_b$V3[tab_A$V3])

df

      ###
  id gr   V1   V2   V3
1 01  A <NA>    0 <NA>
2 02  A <NA> <NA>    4
3 03  A    5 <NA> <NA>
4 01  B    2 <NA>    4
5 02  B <NA>    1 <NA>
6 03  B <NA>    1    4
7 01  C <NA>    5 <NA>
8 02  C    9 <NA>    3
9 03  C    9 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: thank you, but why can help me with more than 2000 column? May I escape to define each columns?

Comment: Yes thats possible but a different question :)  Could you include an example of the multiple column frame you are dealing with?

Comment: I don't know how to implement your @MarkeD subsetting  within loop. Below is sample data, sample.csv = tab_A, dat.csv = tab_b https://www.dropbox.com/s/e9vw93sh51w5800/dat.csv?dl=0   https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wb8lk60adzbc12/sample.csv?dl=0